# Using css .first to create list item dividers

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Please reference the this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uJdhH/):

I'm trying to create vertical dividers between my list items (But not at the ends) using a combination of left-border and .first css rules.  How come I still have a border in front of the first element?

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li {
    display:inline;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    padding-left:6px;
}

ul li.first {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Comment: Yarin - can you post your code into the question so that it's easily available to future users?  It's helpful when reading the Answer to have the code up here in the Question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for `:first-child` and not `.first` ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/uJdhH/1/))

```
ul li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
```

To further clarify, `.first` ([link](http://www.quackit.com/css/tutorial/css_class.cfm)) implies a class named `first` whereas `:first-child` ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_firstchild.asp)) is a pseudo-selector

Answer (score 3):

You're using the CSS wrong. `.first` is a class, named first `:first-child` is a pseudo class resolving to exactly the first child.

Check this revised [fork on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/XadmT/).

Answer (score 2):

You should use first-child instead of .first. The dot indicates a classname instead of an selector. Your css would look like this;

```
ul li {
    display:inline;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    padding-left:6px;
}

ul li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
```